# Reading lines from file using BufferedReader

Tags: java

Can I read lines of file between two concrete positions (not begin & and) using BufferedReader in Java? I know how to read all lines from file by this method, but I need to read only one fragment of file.

Comment: 1) Does the file contain records of fixed size? If so, consider using a RandomAccessFile. 2) If not, you can read through the file and start saving the text when you reach your begin position, and then stop reading and close the file once you've passed your end position.

Comment: You can pass over lines until you hit the section you want.

Comment: Can I write like this line = "SomeString" while (line = reader.readLine() != "endString")

Comment: No -- never use `==` or `!=` to compare Strings ever. Use `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` instead.

Comment: while (!(currentLine = reader.readLine()).equals(endLine))??

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can

```
bufferedReader.skip(numberOfCharsToSkip);
```

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#skip%28long%29

Comment: @user2842269: by checking the line returned from the BufferedReader.